# WordPress Featured Images in Child Themes

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child, meta

I'm in the process of moving a website, and on the new location, the featured images no longer work in child themes such as "Noteworthy". I do know with parent themes, the images show up as needed.

I don't think it's a database issue, it's obviously loading the data properly in parent themes. What other troubleshooting methods am I overlooking?

What I had done was refresh the DB table, and tried looking for a plugin. When I go inside the posts, I have the option to set an image manually, but when I use a parent theme the featured images generates from the db_postmeta table and displays.

Thank you!

Edit: I had tried two different child themes, but have no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I overlooked a folder containing all the images. All I had to do was drop this folder in place, and the featured images re-obtained their information.